# Errors using new array functions PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Hello All: I do not have much experience with Arrays but am trying to learn.  Trying something new and don't know if this can be done this way or not.  Essentially what I am trying to do is go through a wp database table; and go through the records; the $postnum value is equivalent to a WP post_id and is in the database multiple times.  So I want to just whip through the table and create an array with each post_id ($postnum) in there just once.  So I thought, all i need to do is create an array outside of loop; then while in loop just check if the $postnum is already in the array; if it is not just add it…so then all records with that same postnum in them they will not add to the array…

here is my code:

```
$posts_counted=array();
global $wpdb;

foreach( $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_c93hh3bk23_pvc_daily") as $key => $row) {

$id = $row->id;
$time = $row->time;
$postnum = $row->postnum;
$postcount = $row->postcount;



if (in_array($postnum,$posts_counted)) 
{
 array_push($posts_counted,$postnum);
}

} // close out foreach
```

I have never really used the "in_array" thing or the "array_push" thing either; so these are all new to me…

I am getting:  "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ' ' (T_STRING) in…"
referring to the line "if (in_array($postnum,$posts_counted))"

So I am wondering if anyone can tell me if what I am trying to do can be done this way or what I am doing wrong on this…

Thanks!

Comment: Replace `$posts_counted` in `if (in_array($postnum,$posts_counted))` with `$postcount`.So it would become like this `if (in_array($postnum,$postcount))`

Comment: is this the complete codes?

Comment: Why are you doing a database query? Why not just use [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)? It returns an array...

Comment: 1. to Rohil:  $posts_counted is the array I create on the very first line of the code; on the other hand; $postcount is a separate variable that is pulled from the database for that record; so they are two separate things; I am trying to add it to the $posts_counted array if it is not already there...

Comment: 2.  to mevius: I cannot use "get_posts()"; this is being pulled from a table from a plugin; which is storing info for the posts; but this is not something that can be accessed by "get_posts()"

Comment: 3. to ghost: yes that is the complete deal; i start the array on first line; then loop through database records with the foreach loop; then while in loop for each record; check to see if the $postnum value for that record is stored in array already; and if not I want to add it with the "array_push" statement...

Comment: Are you sure you've edited the right file / saved it in the right place?  There's no syntax error in that code

Comment: Its working fine when I applied same logic in basic core PHP.Why is it giving you the error?
Have you tried debugging all lines one by one ?

Comment: I have done same thing my WP for `wp_postmeta` table.And its working perfectly without any error and also working the way you want.
You made me curious to know why is It giving you only that error?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, with suggestions from a number of you and also when I started looking into this more, I started breaking apart the code to try and isolate the problem, have not found it explicitly yet but I stripped it way down and got the "in_array" and also the "array_push" to both work; so now all i need do is add stuff back one at a time to see if I can isolate the problem; thanks so much for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I get data from db:

```
$sql= "Select * FROM table";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($rows = mysql_fetchArray($result)){
  $data= $rows;
 }
//checking if something is in array
if(in_array($data['id')){
    //do something
  }
//now how you want to get data
// echo json_encode($data)
 //OUTPUT: {id:"1",name:"xyz"}
```

Anyway if you want your "postNum" unique, fix your sql with adding DISTINCT after SELECT.

Comment: thanks Ales, I cannot use SELECT DISTINCT however because the $postnum value will come up more than once so it is not distinct; I just want to add it to the array once and then stop …thanks...

Comment: another idea... make a flag on $postnum value, if that value is spawned once than save in array(true) otherwise (false) so that means counter for value(how many times value repeat)

Comment: I don't see why you can't use `distinct` - it won't come back multiple times if you do `SELECT distinct postnum FROM wp_c93hh3bk23_pvc_daily`

Comment: Thanks Hobo:  my understanding is that select distinct only selects values that are in there just once; and if they are in there multiple times; it will not select them; which will not work for me, if I am wrong about this please let me know

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, with suggestions from a number of you and also when I started looking into this more, I started breaking apart the code to try and isolate the problem, have not found it explicitly yet but I stripped it way down and got the "in_array" and also the "array_push" to both work; so now all i need do is add stuff back one at a time to see if I can isolate the problem; thanks so much for all of your help!

Comment: Sorry, only just saw your response.  Your understanding of `select distinct` is (was) wrong.  It'll bring each value back just once, even if it exists multiple times.  It won't ignore values.  For example, if `col1` contained 1 / 2 / 2 / 3 / 2 / 3, `select distinct col1 from table` would return 1 / 2 / 3